# Linq to Sql Union statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have two resultsets that I'm trying to union on (LINQ to SQL/Entity)

```
var ldrSet = (from ldr in Leader
              join emp in employee
              on ldr.ID equals emp.ID
              where ldr.ID.Contains("123")
     select new {ID = ldr.ID, Name = emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName, flag = "Edit"});

var allEmpSet = (from emp in employee
                 where emp.ID.Contains("123")
     select new {ID = ldr.ID, Name = emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName, flag = "New"});

var results = ldrSet.Union(allEmpSet);
```

When I run this query I get something like this:

> 123    Joe Blow   Edit
>
> 123    Joe Blow   New
>
> 234    Jane Smith New
>
> 345    John Doe   New

I understand why this is occurring but is there a way to further filter this resultset down by just using ID?

I want one record to return and the `Edit` record trumps the `New` record.  So I just want this:

> 123    Joe Blow   Edit
>
> 234    Jane Smith New
>
> 345    John Doe   New

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to handle things in this case isn't a Union. It's to use a left outer join instead of the inner join that LINQ defaults to. That will allow you to select all of the rows a single time and set the `flag` if data was matched appropriately:

```
var results = from e in employee
              join l in leaders on l.ID equals e.ID into ls
              from l in ls.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { 
                  e.ID, 
                  Name = e.firstName + e.lastName,
                  flag = (p == null ? "New" : "Edit")
              };
```

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the example syntax for a left join.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy` to group records by their ID and select just one of them:

```
var results = ldrSet.Union(allEmpSet)
    .GroupBy(item => item.ID, (key, items) => 
        items.OrderBy(item => item.flag)
        .FirstOrDefault());
```

You can change the contents of `OrderBy` to determine which of the items to choose.

Comment: Technically, this is correct. If you look at the data, though, the better option would be to use a left outer join (the syntax of which is a pain in the ass, but do-able) and set flag to `Edit` when there is a value in the `Leader` table and to `New` when there isn't.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Fair enough.  I pretty much ignored the working portion of the query and just transformed what he had into what he needed.  It may well be the case that he should have altered the query itself to produce the desired results.